# Get complete XML structure stored on mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have this odd problem, I have to read XML structure stored on a mySQL database, one like this:

```
<geocercaPoligonal>
<nombreGeocerca>Kennedy</nombreGeocerca>
<longitud>-79.89726930856705</longitud>
<latitud>-2.1599807309506396</latitud>
<longitud>-79.9029341340065</longitud>
<latitud>-2.172760363061884</latitud>
</geocercaPoligonal>
```

When I get the query on PHP (using PDO Fetch:Assoc) and output the result, it results on this:

```
' Kennedy -79.89726930856705 -2.1599807309506396 -2.172760363061884 -79.9029341340065 '
```

All tags are omitted and this leads to error when reading this data, I must get values from specific tags, I get a XML load string

The DB::getRow its a prepare/execute PDO function

```
    $geocerca = DB::getRow('SELECT * FROM GeocercasxUsuario WHERE IdGeocerca = :IdGeocerca', ['IdGeocerca' => $IdGeocerca]);  
$infoXML = simplexml_load_string($geocerca['InformacionGeografica']);
    //The field from the database with the XML string
```

It gets this info

```
SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
    'nombreGeocerca' => 'Kennedy',
    'longitud' => array(
        0 => '-79.89726930856705',
        1 => '-2.172760363061884',
    ),
    'latitud' => array(
        0 => '-2.1599807309506396',
        1 => '-79.9029341340065',
    ),
))
```

It doesn't read the XML structure properly, how could I fix this? It's something from PHP or mySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying some things, I switched my select statement to get specific XML data like this:

Instead of

```
SELECT * FROM GeocercasxUsuario WHERE IdUsuario = n (just for example)
```

I changed it to

```
SELECT ExtractValue(InformacionGeografica,'/geocercaPoligonal/latitud') AS Latitud, ExtractValue(InformacionGeografica,'/geocercaPoligonal/longitud') AS Longitud, ...(other fields)... FROM GeocercasxUsuario WHERE IdUsuario = n
```

This way I get an XML array of the values of each tag, pretty useful if you only want inner values :)

Answer (score 0):

What in particular is not being read properly? The SimpleXML object contains all the data from your XML.

You can convert the object into an array so it is easier to work with as follows:

```
$json_string = json_encode($infoXML);    
$result_array = json_decode($json_string, TRUE);
```

Comment: It is wrong, you can see that 'longitud' gets the first value right, but the second value corresponds to 'latitud', and doesn't respect ordering

Comment: @Forcefield can we see the content of `$geocerca['InformacionGeografica']`?

Comment: its the first code block on my question, and that is the order I want to get the data :P

Comment: There must be a mistake, that snippet worked fine for me: http://i.imgur.com/ElnOJcC.jpg

Comment: If I do the same getting inputting as string it works fine, but when getting data from database it crashes :(

Comment: Data is disordered when reading from mySQL, I think there must be something I'm doing wrong

Comment: How is the data stored in the database? What type of data is the column?

Comment: Its a TEXT field, stored as string I guess :P

Comment: Found a way to fix this!!